# Grid with relative columns width for Android View

Tags: android, xaml, layout, tablelayout, grid-layout

I'm beginner in Android layouts and came from Xaml.
Is it possible to specify grid (table) with fixed number of columnd and relative width for each other.

For example I have 1 row and 4 columns in my table.
I want:

- First column takes 1 part
- Second takes 2 parts
- Third 10px (absolute value)
- Fourth takes 7 parts

In Xaml I could define it as

```
<Grid>
 ... 
 <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
 <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
 <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
 <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
 ...
</Grid>
```

Result:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/layout.png

There is one more type of width is Auto and column will be collapsed if it contains no children and adjust its width to fit all children

Is it possible to do using Android SDK Layouts? What is the best control suits here?

Thanks!

Comment: Even better: see GridLayout

Comment: @ramaral thank you. GridLayout powerful element. But I'm still don't know how to define weights for columns? I can shrink or stretch them but still wondering how to define weight parts for each column to make layout more natural. For android it is especially critical because of different screen sizes.

Comment: You have to stop thinking in terms of the wpf grid. GridLayout does not have the concept of *. Search examples and play around. What sets the space occupied by each column are the elements placed there and how they are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GridLayout** works perfect in my case. I found several tutorials:

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaCW4uL4P6c (basic)
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mkc1xQ0wsbU (advanced)